# Is $f(0, y) = f(y) \implies f_{y} (0,y) = f'(y)$ true?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

OK, I think I'm being a bit stupid here, but I need to check whether my reasoning here is correct, as I don't want to mess this up. So my question is:

Is $f(0, y) = f(y) \implies f_{y} (0,y) = f'(y)$ true?

It seems to me that it is, but, for some reason, I've gotten confused and am having some trouble getting out of this confusion, and figured I would ask here just to get this straight.

Comment: Your $f$ denotes two different things. – When $f$ is a function of two variables defined in a neighborhood of the $y$-axis, and if $\phi(y):=f(0,y)$ then obviously $\phi'(y)=f_{.2}(0,y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

**This is my initial answer which is wrong**
Nope you may have some $y$'s multiplying $x$'s consider $f(x,y) = xy$

$$f(y) = f(0,y)= 0 \Rightarrow f'(y)=0$$

$$ f_y(x,y)=y \Rightarrow f_y(0,y)=y $$

---

It is **true** which can be seen from the definition of the partial derivative.

$$ f_y(0,y)= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0,y+h)-f(0,y)}{h} = f'(y) $$

Comment: For $f(x,y) = xy$, you have $f_y(x,y) = x$. It works.

Comment: Woops, you're right. Too sloppy there.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I was just about to say the same thing. But is the statement in my question still false, as Spencer suggested?

Comment: @Ryker No, it's true. One has to be very careful however to not use it when one might veer off $x = 0$.

Comment: Its definitely true, follows directly from the definition of the partial derivative.

Comment: Thanks to both. I actually wrote it all down and couldn't see why it wouldn't be true, but I needed to double check, because I didn't want to get something as basic as this confused.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for point out my mistake.